# control amount of loops (batch file)

Tags: batch-file

I am wondering if there is a way to put a limit on a loop for a batch file.
What I mean is this:   say I have a script:

```
@echo off
:start
echo Enter the password
set /p password=
if %password%== abcdefg goto correct
if not %password%== abcdefg goto start
:correct
echo good job
timeout 2 > nul
exit
:wrong
echo You are wrong
timeout 1 > nul
exit
```

say I wanted you to go through start three times, and after that, you go to wrong.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%a in (1, 1, 3) do (
set /p "password=Enter the password: "
if "!password!"=="abcdefg" goto :correct
echo You are wrong, try again
timeout /t 1 >nul
)
exit
:correct
echo good job
timeout /t 2 > nul
exit
```

Comment: so i just need     setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /L %%a in (1, 1, 3) do (             after :start, and the ) right?

Comment: I don't understand your query.  The delayed expansion allows you to check a !variable! within a loop.  The for /L implements a simple loop here.